# Выпадающие списки в Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

Есть ячейка таблицы с выпадающим списком. В ячейке установлено значение и нужно чтобы при появлении выпадающего списка, он начинался (автопрокручивался до) с текущего значения в ячейке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Просто поставьте соответствующее значение для свойства 'value' вашего комбобокса. В value должно быть значение, которое указано в valueField, как то так

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
data : [
    {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
    {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
    {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"},
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    {"abbr":"testValue", "name":"it's work!"}

]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    value: 'testValue',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```